# Track transactions for a list of addreses not in a wallet

Tags: address, payment

I am developing a payment gateway for BTC and have the following problem. I have bitcoind wallet and awaiting of some income for some some list of generated addresses. If i have received something on a the address I remove it from my wait list and make transaction complete. There are a lot of online services that allows me to look transactions or even some JSON-rpc solutions like blockchain.com allow to do it.

But I am wondering if it is possible to do it just using bitcoin-cli RPC protocol and without adding all ammount of addresses to the wallet.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Core does not allow you to track transactions for addresses that are not in your wallet.

If you wish to do this, you will need to maintain a separate index outside of the bitcoind node, either by scanning each incoming block for transactions involving your address, or by using an external api such as Blockchain.com or insight to query for your addresses.

Comment: Yes, bitcoin core does not allow it but it is a pretty common task and may be there are exist some opensource solutions that can allow to do it .

Comment: Insight is a patched version of bitcoin core that adds address indexing. However, it has not been updated for a few versions, so it's not great for the current network.